# Calculating vector ab from vector a and b.

Tags: vectors

So I have a vector $a =( 2 ,2 )$ and a vector $b =( 0, 1 )$.
As my teacher told me, $ab =  (-2, -1 )$.

$ab = b-a = ( 0, 1 ) - ( 2, 2 ) = ( 0-2, 1-2 ) = ( -2, -1 )$
$ab = a-b = ( 2 ,2 ) - ( 0 ,1 ) = ( 2-0,2-1 ) = ( 2 ,1 )$

Seems like its the same but the negative signs are gone.

Why do I have to subtract b from a to get ab?  Why not a-b or a+b?

Comment: You write in the same line $\;b-a\;$ , which is the correct thing to get the direction vector $\;\vec{ab}\;$ , and **also** $\;a-b\;$. How can this be possible?

Comment: @Joanpemo i didnt mean to write both equations in the same line if thats what you meant. I edited my question.

Comment: As a comment, when you say vector $a$ , I assume you are talking about vector $\vec{OA}$ and vector $ab$ is vector $\vec{AB}$?

Comment: @Martigan Yes, I do.

Comment: Vectors are not lines. Where you start is critical. Your $a-b$ will have the same magnitude as $b-a$ but is incorrect

Answer (score 6):

They are related by the fact that $$\mathbf a- \mathbf b = -(\mathbf b- \mathbf a)$$

The difference is the direction. Generally, the vector from a starting point to an ending point is $$(\textrm{terminal point})-(\textrm{initial point})$$

Answer (score 3):

( Vector AB ) = ( Vector B ) - ( Vector A )

Think of this logically when you have the equation 10 - 2 you get 8 ( a positve value )
However if you do 2 - 10 you get the same magnitude 8 but opposite direction -8.

Use this to understand the vectors since the point of Vector AB is moving from A to B you want to know whether its moving in the positive of negative direction.

If B had a greater value of position than A then obviously it moved in the 
positive direction to achieve that greater value and that is why B - A (larger - smaller ) has to be positive. If it  had a lesser value than A then it moved in the negative direction and that is why the value of B - A would then be negative (smaller - larger).

And in reality you are subtraction the vectors OB - OA ( O being the point of origin ) so the difference between these to vectors is a displacement.

I really hope i was of any help to answer your question.

:)

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing is $\;b-a\;$ for the direction vector $\;\vec{ab}\;$. The substraction $\;a-b\;$ gives *the opposite* direction vector, namely $\;\vec
{ba}\;$

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to answer. Also I do not have a lot of knowledge of Mathematics. But I will try and simplify. Please do not refrain from commenting if I get it horribly or event slightly wrong.

Now to simplify lets us first imagine things in one dimensions. That is a number line. Now we have 2 points on a number line a and b.

b can either be in the positive direction ie right of a, or in the negative direction ie left of a.

So to find the direction from a to b ie ab, we will substract a from b ie b - a. So if b is greater than a (ie in positive direction)  we will get a positive answer or if b is lesser than a (ie in negative direction)  we will get a negative answer.

Now when we move to 2D the same logic is applied to find the direction, hence

ab = b - a
ie direction from a to b.

and
ba = a - b
ie direction from b to a.

Also it is important to understand that direction from a to b and b to a are different values.

Hope this helps.